# Add style to the button

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/interactivedesigner/2006"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                <Button Style="{StaticResource Button}"/>
                                <Button />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Grid Name="xGrid">
                            <Border>
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="Button" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF000000" />
        </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I'm trying to add a style to the button, but If I add it (`<Button Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource Button}"/>`) in the project, my project doesn't run, and VS don't show me an exception.

My styles are saved in a separate file.

Why can not I add a style to the button? And what exception do VS not show me?

I will accept any help.

Thanks.

p.s. Sorry for the mistake, if any.

**EDIT #1:**

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             StartupUri="View\MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**EDIT #2:**

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Transparent"
    WindowStyle="None"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

            <Grid>
                <TabControl>
                    <TabItem Header="jhb">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        </Grid>
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem" />
                </TabControl>
            </Grid>
  </Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you merge your `ResourceDictionary` into your `App.xaml`?

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Replace `Dictionary1.xaml` with the actual name of your `ResourceDictionary` file.

Comment: Just for further clarification, the `ResourceDictionary` (or somewhere else in the document, or a linked document) should be providing the value(s) for the `StaticResource` key: `Button` -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/staticresource-markup-extension

Comment: Here It's all right. The situation is that without a style everything works, but when i add the style to the button the project does not work.

Comment: So where is your ResourceDictionary merged and where is your Button located?

Comment: My ResourceDictionary is located at root folder of project. The button is is located in ResourceDictionary:
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">...<Button Style="{StaticResource Button}"/><Button />...</Style>. Full content you may look on top.

Comment: You need to merge it into your application somehow. You cannot just add a file to the project...Did you read my answer? Where is your ResourceDictionary *merged*?

Comment: If you mean App.xaml. It is. And it had correct link to ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Please provide a repo of your issue when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The last style of "Button" need move before style of "TabControl".

Thanks VladD.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/713288/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-resourcedictionary